# Getting error while trying to write to DB

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-insert

I am currently facing a problem with writing to database table some info on java. I keep getting

> java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Note that the table is already created and exists.

```
 public static void includeToDB(File file, String email) throws  Exception{
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resSet = null;
    Date now = new Date();

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        String sql = "INSERT INTO T_EQ_STATEMENT_FILE_TRANS_LOG"
                + "(SENTDATE, FILENAME, EMAIL) " + "VALUES "
                + "("+ getCurrentTimeStamp() + "," + file.getName() + "," + email + ")";
             /*   "INSERT INTO CAMEL.T_EQ_STATEMENT_FILE_TRANS_LOG" +
                "           VALUES (" +
                            now + "," +
                            file.getName() + "," +
                            email + ");";
                            */
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

        if(resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println("[DB_Handler] Information about sent file has been written to the DB... ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("[DB_Handler] Something went wrong, and writing the info has failed...");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(EQSFT_ERROR_TYPE.SQL_EXCEPTION.getErrorToPrint(), e);
        logger.error("Messgage: " + e.getMessage());
        logger.error("Error code: " + e.getErrorCode());
        logger.error("SQL state: " + e.getSQLState());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(EQSFT_ERROR_TYPE.UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION.getErrorToPrint(), e);
    } finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the values need to be 'quoted'?  Probably should use a `PreparedStatement` instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) when you have to set  IN parameters

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO T_EQ_STATEMENT_FILE_TRANS_LOG(SENTDATE, FILENAME, EMAIL) values (?,?,?)”;
PreparedStatement pstm = connection.preparedStatement(sql);
pstm.setTimeStamp(1,getCurrentTimeStamp());
pstm.setString(2,file.getName());
pstm.setString(3,email);
```

Comment: thank you a lot. this solved my problem. Never knew about this (?,?,?). Will remember it from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO T_EQ_STATEMENT_FILE_TRANS_LOG"
                + "(SENTDATE, FILENAME, EMAIL) VALUES "
                + "(sysdate,'" + file.getName() + "','" + email + "')";
```

You're missing the quotes around the strings and I'm not sure that your "time/date" format is acceptable by Oracle.

*Comment*: a better practice would be using the setParameters the way Prabhaker showed!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void includeToDB(File file, String email) throws  Exception{
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resSet = null;
    Date now = new Date();

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        String sql = "INSERT INTO T_EQ_STATEMENT_FILE_TRANS_LOG"
                + "(SENTDATE, FILENAME, EMAIL) " + "VALUES "
                + "(?,?,?)";
             /*   "INSERT INTO CAMEL.T_EQ_STATEMENT_FILE_TRANS_LOG" +
                "           VALUES (" +
                            now + "," +
                            file.getName() + "," +
                            email + ");";
                            */
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setTimestamp(1, getCurrentTimeStamp() );
        statement.setString(2, file.getName());
        statement.setString(3,email);

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

        if(resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println("[DB_Handler] Information about sent file has been written to the DB... ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("[DB_Handler] Something went wrong, and writing the info has failed...");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(EQSFT_ERROR_TYPE.SQL_EXCEPTION.getErrorToPrint(), e);
        logger.error("Messgage: " + e.getMessage());
        logger.error("Error code: " + e.getErrorCode());
        logger.error("SQL state: " + e.getSQLState());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(EQSFT_ERROR_TYPE.UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION.getErrorToPrint(), e);
    } finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

You have to use parameterized query as shown above.

You can also use Statement and CallableStatement.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-statements.htm

Answer (score 0):

BTW, even though the Javadoc specifies that [`executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-) never returns `null`, using `executeQuery` on a statement you know is not a query is a bad practice. The proper way to check if a record was inserted is to use the update count:

```
/* PreparedStatement constructed and used as demonstrated by Prabhaker */
int count = statement.executeUpdate();

if (count > 0) {
  System.out.println("[DB_Handler] Information about sent file has been written to the DB... ");
} else {
  System.out.println("[DB_Handler] Something went wrong, and writing the info has failed...");
}
```

Comment: yes this method helped me as well. thank you a lot. it saved so much trouble. now program is working good and inserts data to table.